# Why does my flask route not return "Success!"?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I've been stuck on this for the last 6 hours. I wrote more than 100 lines of code for this single route and it didn't work. So I spent the last hours trying to find the error and realized, that the basic functionality of receiving the POST request does not even work and I cannot wrap my head around what is wrong.

So here is what I am trying to do: I have a very basic form that has three fields and a submit button. I want to display it in the search.html file. When going to /search, the HTML is rendered perfectly with the fields as it should. I type in parameters and submit. For the last hours I have not received a single error. I just see: `127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2019 01:42:52] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

200 means the POST request is received, right? But it DOES NOT return "Success!". It just returns the search.html again as if nothing happened.

What am I doint wrong here? Please help because the last hours were the most frustrating debugging sessions without any errors that I have ever encountered.

routes.py:

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def search():
     if 'code' not in session:
         return redirect(url_for('secret'))
     if 'email' not in session:
         return redirect(url_for('login'))
     else:
        form = SearchForm()
         return render_template('search.html', form=form)
         if request.method == 'POST':
             if form.validate() == False:
                 return render_template("search.html", form=form)
             else:
                 return "Success!"
```

forms.py:

```
class SearchForm(Form):
     place = StringField('place', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter a place.")])
     radius = IntegerField('radius', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter a number between 1 and 100000"), NumberRange(min=1, max=100000)])
     keyword = StringField('keyword', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter a keyword.")])
     submit = SubmitField("Search")
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/search">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ form.place }}
      {{ form.radius }}
      {{ form.keyword }}
      {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

Comment: No code after a `return` will be executed.

Comment: thank you so much... that is indeed the answer... I did not know that after a return nothing else gets executed and this is indeed what is happening. Again: Thanks for your help.